# Memory limit issues when attempting to run Wordpress site locally

Tags: php, apache, wordpress, mamp, memory-limit

I'm working on a wordpress website and I'm attempting to set up a local test-environment for development purposes. I'm running the MAMP (Mac Apache MySQL PHP) stack.

I'm running into the following error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4864 bytes) in /Users/casey/Documents/workspaces/yofreesamples.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1174
```

I've attempted to increase the memory limit by modifying line 28 in wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '2024MB');
```

and by including the following value in index.php

```
ini_set('memory_limit','64M');
```

without any luck for any memory values I've tried. I'm relatively new to wordpress, anyone have any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the MAMP configuration doesn't allow you to override the memory limit programmatically. Set it in php.ini as described [here](http://blog-en.mamp.info/2009/09/increase-php-memory-limit-with-mamp-pro.html).

Comment: it's strange: I've modified my php.ini file and set the memory limit there, however wordpress still does not throw a different error.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after modifying php.ini?  Also keep in mind some systems (eg some linux distributions) have a separate php.ini for the command line and for the web.  Make sure you're modifying the right one.

Comment: Use phpinfo() for the actual settings, and, maybe more important, the location of the php.ini file.